# How to add custom header to zend Mail\Message

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-mail

I am using Zend\Mail\Message to send an emails.Need to add some custom headers to mail but Mail\Message don't have addHeader() function.I am using Zend Framework 2.Is there any other function which can be used to add custom headers to mails.I had referred [link](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mail.additional-headers.html) in documentation.But I can not find addHeader in Mail\Message.
zend-mail version is 2.10.0

Comment: It's method `addHeader()` - not with underscore in name but rather camelCased.

Comment: Sorry that was typo updated the question

Comment: What is error/output when you use `addHeader('X-Key', 'value')`?

Comment: addHeader() method not found.I had checked with class also \Mail\Message it don't have this function

Comment: Double check in composer file what version you are using there.

Comment: yes its zendframework/zend-mail 2.10.0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190709/discussion-between-tpojka-and-yogesh).

Comment: @Yogesh Hi, any news on this ?

Comment: @GrecoJonathan Added answer how I did it

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation you should consider to use the headers like this :

```
$message->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('X-API-Key', 'FOO-BAR-BAZ-BAT');
```

Full documentation is found [here](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-mail/message/intro/)

Answer (score 0):

Issue with following is it append <=?UTF-8?Q?$header?=>: to value
`$this->getHeaders()->addHeader($header)` but I was needing plain headers.

I had created Custom class which extends the \Zend\Mail\Header\HeaderInterface
And overwrite `public static function fromString` function. Passed the header as follows

```
$customHeader = CustomHeaderClass::fromString($header);
$this->getHeaders()->addHeader($customHeader);
```